# swfobject : how to add html title attribute to object (flash)

Tags: javascript, swfobject

I use swfobject.js file to embed flash content onto my website. How does one add the html title attribute to the flash-object embed through it.

Since, some of the browsers do show the title of the object on mouseover or in status, as a tooltip or in browser status. [ Eg. IE6 and Opera ]

Please help

Anita

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a forum. Read the [FAQ]. You can leave comments on answers if you think they don't address your question. In addition to that, you can edit your question to clarify it.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in variables to a Flash file, and enable the tooltip in a cross-platform way.

```
so.addVariable("var", "value");
```

Get the value from DOM:

```
document.title
```

So:

```
var mytitle;
var = document.title;
so.addVariable("mytitle", mytitle);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [SWFObject 2.2](http://learnswfobject.com/the-basics/advanced-options-with-dynamic-publishing/)

```
var attributes = {
   title: document.title
};
swfobject.embedSWF("mymovie.swf", //URL for SWF file
                   "mytargetdiv", //Target element
                   "550",         //SWF width
                   "400",         //SWF height
                   "9",           //Minimum required version of Flash Player
                   false,         //Path to ExpressInstall SWF (if desired)
                   false,         //Flashvars (if desired)
                   false,         //Parameters (if desired)
                   attributes);   //Attributes (if desired)
```

This assumes your `<title>` element is placed before your `<script>` element in your page's markup.